# Distorted output waveform and snubber heating in 3level 3 phase inverter

Tags: inverter, mosfet-driver, three-phase, snubber

We are working on 3-level 3-phase 400Hz inverter (110Vrms).

The problem is that the output wave still have some harmonics of the switching frequency.
The snubbers are heating up rapidly when connected to load.(11 Ohm balanced 3 phase load).

Input voltage is -75V 0V +75V

We are using SVPWM algorithm.
(C2000 board from Texas Instruments)
No.of vectors :175
Switching frequency :70KHz

For driver circuit we are using TLP350 for driving the mosfet.
Mosfet specs are 500V 80Amp

For snubbers we are using RCD snubbing
R :1kohm 5Watt
C :2.2nF 600V

For filtering the output wave we have used LC low pass filter with cutoff frequency 405Hz.
L : 20mH
C : 7.7uF

When i looked at the gate signal it is going in negative voltage for some time which is causing ringing in drain to source. refer to picture 1

Now please guide me how to overcome this drain to source ringing?
And how can the heating of snubbers be minimized.

[image: the blue one is drain to source signal and the yellow is gate to source signal for the mosfet (in unloded condition)]

[image: this is the output wave form after LC filtering but still has ringing]

[image: this is the output waveform before the LC filtering]

Comment: inductance in the source circuit can cause ringing. It might also be a ghost due to exactly how you've probed it with the oscilloscope. Consider your current paths and ensure you minimise inductance by keeping the connections short and using thick conductors.

Comment: Agree with @Kartman.  Can you show your layout?